# openssl smime encrypt and decrypt

Tags: encryption, openssl, smime

I'm trying to encrypt and decrypt using openssl. Here's what I do to encrypt
   `openssl smime -encrypt -binary -des -in in1.txt -out out1.dat   -nosigs my.crt`

out1.dat gets created.

However when I try to decrypt using the command
   `openssl smime -decrypt  -in out1.dat -inkey my.key -out f`

I get

```
`Error decrypting PKCS#7 structure
140278455719752:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:evp_enc.c:596:`
```

My key, certificate looks fine. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: This is exactly the error I get if the privatekey **does not match** the certificate. Compare `openssl x509 -in my.crt -noout -modulus` to `openssl rsa -in my.key -noout -modulus`.

Comment: thanks .. what I did not realize is that the CRT included the entire chain and this made a difference. you answered my question

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).